# Reconciling two different ways of thing about the derivative

Tags: functional-analysis, derivatives, hilbert-spaces, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds

For the last 3 months or so I have been studying differential topology, which has led to me completely changing how I think about the derivative. In pretty much every case now, when talking about the derivative of a smooth function $F$ between two smooth manifolds $M$, and $N$, I think about it as a linear map $dF$ that maps from $T_pM$ to  $T_F(p)N$.

I like this way of thinking about the derivative quite a bit as it is readily apparent that it is equivalent to the Jacobian as a linear map, and $dF(v)$ is the same as the directional derivative of $F$ in the direction of $v$ if $M=\mathbb{R}^m$ and $N=\mathbb{R}^n$. Furthermore, if $M=N=\mathbb{R}$ and $v=1\in \mathbb{R}$ we get the derivative that we first learn when we first learn calculus. So essentially I like thinking about the derivative in this way because it's general enough that it can be applied to almost any situation I am in.

The issue is now that I have come to the realization that when I am working on Quantum Mechanics problems, and a derivative shows up I think of it as a linear operator on a Hilbert space, and I do not know how to relate these two ways of thinking about the derivative since in this case the functions themselves are being mapped from one state to another.

Is there any connection between these two ways of thinking about the derivative? If so what is it? I'm sorry if this worded weirdly I kind of don't exactly know how to explain where my confusion is.

Comment: You certainly can talk about the derivative in the setting of mappings on Banach spaces and Banach manifolds. But you'll have to make your QM issue very explicit if you expect us to comment. :)

Comment: I mean I’m not sure how to make it more explicit, In my undergrad quantum class we treated the derivative as a linear operator on a vector and we solved for it’s eigenvectors which were exponential functions. Does that clarify at all?

Comment: @TedShifrin ok so I think I can boil down two how do I reconcile thinking about the derivative of a function as a linear map between tangent spaces of smooth manifolds versus thinking about the derivative as a linear map sending one function as a vector to another function

Comment: You are looking at mappings between vector spaces whose elements are functions. Thus, tangent vectors are again functions.

Comment: @TedShifrin so if $V=C^\infty(M\rightarrow N)$ and $W=\text{Hom}(TM\rightarrow TN)$ then is the derivative just the linear map $V\rightarrow W$?

Comment: Well, smooth maps from one manifold to another (in that generality) is not a vector space. How do you add two maps or scalar multiply a map? I think you've leapt a little too far here.

Comment: @TedShifrin ok I see that I was a bit brash with that comment, that’s clearly not a vector space. How can I bring it back a bit?

Comment: @TedShifrin I just reached the group action section of the book on gauge theory I’m reading and they define the group action on a smooth manifold as a homomorphism from G to the set of diffemorphism on the manifold, so the set of diffeomorphism in a smooth manifold has a group structure. Is this what I should look into? Are there similar structures on smooth maps that aren’t diffeomorphisms?